# Check if an item exist in a nested list in R

Tags: r, list, function, nested-lists

I have a data.frame that looks like this (data available here : https://github.com/JMcrocs/MEPVote/blob/master/MEP_ID_EPG.rds)

```
head(MEP_ID_EPG)
   mepid     EPG
1 197701 GUE.NGL
2 197533 GUE.NGL
3 197521 GUE.NGL
```

and a large list of 2336 lists (data : https://github.com/JMcrocs/MEPVote/blob/master/AllVotes.rds)

```
str(AllVotes, max.level = 7, list.len = 5)
List of 2336
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ votes  :List of 3
  .. ..$ +:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ total : num 83
  .. .. ..$ groups:List of 6
  .. .. .. ..$ GUE/NGL  :List of 23
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : Named num 197701
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mepid"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : Named num 197533
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mepid"
  .. ..$ -:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ total : num 142
  .. .. ..$ groups:List of 8
  .. .. .. ..$ ECR      :List of 27
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : Named num 198096
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mepid"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : Named num 197467 
  .. ..$ 0:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ total : num 72
  .. .. ..$ groups:List of 4
  .. .. .. ..$ ID       :List of 3
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : Named num 197480
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mepid"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : Named num 197482
```

My goal is to add a "+", a "-" or a "0" in the row of the MEP (mepid) in MEP_ID_EPG if he voted yea("+"), nay("-") or other ("0") if NA or he voted ("0").
In a more complex language, it should look like this

if(
MEP_ID_EPG$mepid is in a sublist of AllVotes[[x]]$votes$'+'

then MEP_ID_EPG$[[x]] == '+')

if(MEP_ID_EPG$mepid is in a sublist of AllVotes[[x]]$votes$'-'

then MEP_ID_EPG$[[x]] == '-')

else('0')

and the outcome should look like this

```
head(MEP_ID_EPG)
   mepid     EPG      1     2  ... 2336
1 197701 GUE.NGL     +      +  ... +
2 197533 GUE.NGL     0     +   ... 0
3 197521 GUE.NGL      -     0  ... -
```

For now I can only do that

```
MEP_ID_EPG$mepid %in% AllVotes[[1]]$votes$'+'$groups$`GUE/NGL`[[1]]
```

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AllVotes is an unnamed list of 2336 elements, each is a particular voting session. So we'll need to loop on its elements for example with `map()`, or `lapply()`, or a `for` loop.

In addition, for a given session `i`, the IDs of the MEPs who voted `+` can be obtained with:

```
unlist(AllVotes[[i]]$votes$`+`$groups)
```

and same for `-` and `0`.

Since you want the output to be with a column for each election, let's create a blank table and fill it. I'll use a matrix which I find slightly more practical here.

```
meps2 <- matrix(NA_character_,
                nrow = nrow(meps),
                ncol=length(AllVotes),
                dimnames = list(meps$mepid,
                                as.character(1:length(AllVotes))))

for(i in 1:length(AllVotes)){
  meps2[as.character(unlist(AllVotes[[i]]$votes$`+`$groups)), i] <- "+"
  meps2[as.character(unlist(AllVotes[[i]]$votes$`-`$groups)), i] <- "-"
  meps2[as.character(unlist(AllVotes[[i]]$votes$`0`$groups)), i] <- "0"
}
```

For loops are not generally recommended in R, but here it works quite well enough, I'm not sure there would be any gain with an apply-family function.

Take a look:

```
meps2[1:10,1:10]
table(is.na(meps2))
# -> note there still are lots of NA.
# Possibly MEPs that were not present?
```

And finally we just need to assemble the final table. The row order is the same, so we don't even need `merge` or `match`.

```
meps <- cbind(meps, meps2)
```

EDIT: your idea of using a `%in%` would work, but its not very efficient. You would need to loop on every voting session, extract the 3 lists of voters, then loop for every MEP on each list applying a `%in%` (which is a loop itself). That would be 3 loops. Here by reversing the problem, we're looping explicitly on the voting sessions and implicitly on the MEPs from each list (-, +, 0). That's only 2 loops, and filling specific rows in a matrix is pretty efficient. It could look something like (with a proper initialization):

```
for(vote in AllVotes){
  voters_+ <- unlist(AllVotes[[i]]$votes$`+`$groups)
  voters_- <- unlist(AllVotes[[i]]$votes$`-`$groups)
  voters_0 <- unlist(AllVotes[[i]]$votes$`0`$groups)
  
  meps[,vote] <-ifelse(meps$mepid %in% voters_+, "+",
          ifelse(meps$mepid %in% voters_-, "-",
          ifelse(meps$mepid %in% voters_0, "0", NA)))
}
```

Comment: Your answer is incredible! Kind Well explained too! I struggle a lot with data manipulation in R and I finally understood everything. I won't just copy/paste! Thank you very much! Have a nice day, night or whatever..you made a man happy today !

Comment: Sadly, as I understood everything on paper...I have "Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, as.character(unlist(AllVotes[[i]]$votes$`+`$groups)),  : indice hors limite (subscript out of bounds ?)" when I try the 'for' command. For the NA, some MEPs left the European Parliament and some joined recently (Brexit means Brexit apparently)

Comment: That means one of the mepids in `as.character(unlist(AllVotes[[i]]$votes$+$groups))` in not found in the rownames. You can manually check what these ids look like and what the rownames look like to understand the discrepancy. I tested the solution in my answer so that one should work (not the one in the edit though).

Comment: it was a dumb mistake!